# Any good Wizard libraries for Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wizard

I'm looking for a good "Wizard" library for Winforms.
WYSIWYG editor preferrable, but not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have to role your own. It's not that hard. I wrote one in under 30 minutes.

Here's two links to help you out:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/visualstudionetadd-ins/article.php/c6911/
http://www.differentpla.net/content/2005/02/implementing-wizard-c

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress has an excellent [wizard control](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Wizard/) but most usually do roll their own.