# Creating Wizards for Win Forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any framework or tutorial on how to create a wizard in C#. I need to provide the user a way to do a sequence of selections/user inputs. I thought Wizards would be an ideal way. I need Next/Back buttons on each page. I haven't created wizards yet. Any inputs would be very helpful.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613232/any-good-wizard-libraries-for-winforms

Comment: Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-wizard-in-c-2-0

Comment: Unfortunately most wizards seem to be driven by navigation, not data. We use a custom wizard that inverts this (common) approach to emphasis tasks and state transitions. OTOH, XtraWizard is very nice, but still follows in the same (common) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the [DevExpress XtraWizard](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Wizard/) control to be quite nice to work with

Comment: Yes, XtraWizard is pretty, but it still keeps step tightly coupled with each-other.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a brief article for CodeProject on a "poor man's wizard" that uses the standard WinForms TabControl as its "foundation" : but that won't be ready for a few weeks.

But think about the advantages using the standard WinForms TabControl gives you :

1. "less code" == "cheap" : it will handle all the "business" suggested by Manzoor Ahmed's comment above (swapping in and out a bunch of panels), with much less code.
2. "no painting" == "less work" : it can be used without any special ownerdraw or painting code (the Simmons article on CodeProject cited by Jay Riggs above has some optional custom painting for gradients, but I have not examined that code in depth to see if it can be used without *any* custom drawing/painting). Note, of course, that Manzoor's suggestion would also not demand custom drawing/painting.
3. flexibility in UI : you can show the Tabs, or hide them.

Here's two ideas on how to start using the TabControl as a "wizard" :

I : how to hide the Tabs themselves if you don't want them visible (assuming a TabControl named tabControl1 on a Form named Form1) :

a. if you want to restore visibility of the Tabs : create a Form scoped variable of type Region, and in the Form Load event put the current Region of the TabControl into that variable :

```
Region tabOriginalRegion;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabOriginalRegion = tabControl1.Region;
}
```

b. add this to the Form Load event to hide the Tabs

```
// hide the tabs
tabControl1.Region = new Region(tabControl1.DisplayRectangle);
```

II : once the tabs are hidden : then, obviously you'll put your own buttons on each tab page to control forward and back movement. if the tabs *are* visible, then you'll want to handle the TabControl's 'Selecting event : inside that Event handler you can use e.TabPage to get the "destination" Tab, and you can cancel navigation to that "destination" tab by setting e.Cancel = true.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: This is BEAUTIFUL!  It works in .Net 8 Winforms.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this one from CodeProject:

[Wizard Form Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WizardForm.aspx)

[Search CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=wizard) for other wizards.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

[C# Winforms Wizard — CodeGuru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/visualstudionetadd-ins/article.php/c6911/)

Alternatively, you can use panels too. Every time you move forward or backward, just change the panels.

Comment: This is predominately a Meta Wizard (a Wizard for *form creation*), and not a general "Wizard Control".