# How to add windows on the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that when I click the "next" button, another window appears with the same form or other components appear.

I tried to add a panel on the main form with two buttons "home" and "next" and then a panel where you can see other forms to give the feeling that the page is changing. In the constructor I try to pass the previous form and the main one so that when clicked it returns to it with all its elements.

```
DesktopReserve formPadre;
DesktopPrincipal deskPrincipal;

public Form1(DesktopReserve formPadre, DesktopPrincipal deskPrincipal)
{
  InitializeComponent();
            
  this.formPadre = formPadre;
  this.deskPrincipal = deskPrincipal;
  this.deskPrincipal.returnButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.returnButton_Click);
}
```

I understand that this is not the best way to do it. Apart from the fact that when I show the different forms within this panel it shows in another size, I would like to know a more efficient way to execute this.

Comment: you can use `TabControl`

Comment: The usual way is to create a series of UserControls and display them usually in a Form. A UC is like a form but meant to be part of some container. Lots of examples around here.. - Have a list of instances of the UCs you created and let the user move forwanrd and back, like a wizard..

Comment: A multi-step form is sometimes called a "wizard." See [Creating Wizards for Winforms in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084048/creating-wizards-for-win-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the name of what I was trying to do, now I can implement it in a better way