# How to open a new form from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0

I have form which is opened using ShowDialog Method. In this form i have a Button called More.
If we click on More it should open another form and it should close the current form.

on More Button's Click event Handler i have written the following code

```
MoreActions objUI = new MoreActions (); 
objUI.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

But what is happening is, it's not closing the first form. So, i modified this code to

```
MoreActions objUI = new MoreActions (); 
objUI.Show();
this.Close();
```

Here, The second form is getting displayed and within seconds both the forms getting closed.

Can anybody please help me to fix issue.  What i need to do is, If we click on More Button, it should open another form and close the first form.

Any kind of help will be really helpful to me.

Comment: I think you need Wizard see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613232/any-good-wizard-libraries-for-winforms

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In my opinion the main form should be responsible for opening both child form. Here is some pseudo that explains what I would do:

```
// MainForm
private ChildForm childForm;
private MoreForm moreForm;

ButtonThatOpenTheFirstChildForm_Click()
{
    childForm = CreateTheChildForm();
    childForm.MoreClick += More_Click;
    childForm.Show();
}

More_Click()
{
    childForm.Close();
    moreForm = new MoreForm();
    moreForm.Show();
}
```

You will just need to create a simple event MoreClick in the first child. The main benefit of this approach is that you can replicate it as needed and you can very easily model some sort of basic workflow.

Comment: In winforms the use of events to manipulate the GUI is the basic of all "smart" stuff. Events are definitly the way to go here +1

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to attach to the `Form.BeforeClosing` event and check to see if the reason it's closing is due to the button - then just have the more button close the form? This would be cleaner/require less code versus defining a new event on the Form.

Comment: @deed02392, what if at some point you want to open the next form without closing the first one? My solution is generic and requires less change in that case. Oh and shorter does not necessarily mean cleaner :p

Answer (score 60):

If I got you right, are you trying like this?

[image]

into this?
[image]

in your **Form1**, add this event in your button:

```
    // button event in your Form1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form2
    }
```

then, in your **Form2** add also this event in your button:

```
    // button event in your Form2
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(); // Instantiate a Form3 object.
        f3.Show(); // Show Form3 and
        this.Close(); // closes the Form2 instance.
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use f2.ShowDialog(); in the first case and f3.Show() in the second case?

Comment: For one linear: `new Form2().Show();`

Answer (score 18):

ok so I used this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 myForm = new Form2();
        this.Hide();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This seems to be working fine but the first form is just hidden and it can still generate events. the "this.Close()" is needed to close the first form but if you still want your form to run (and not act like a launcher) you MUST replace it with

```
this.Show();
```

Best of luck!

Comment: This question already has an answer selected, and it was last active over 6 months ago.  You may want to consider leaving a comment in this situation instead of posting another answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a value that gets set when more button get pushed closed the first dialog and then have the original form test the value and then display the the there dialog.

For the Ex

1. Create three windows froms

   Form1 Form2 Form3

   Add One button to Form1

   Add Two buttons to form2

#### Form 1 Code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool DrawText = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        if (f2.ShowMoreActions)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
```

#### Form2 code

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
 {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool ShowMoreActions = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowMoreActions = true;
            this.Close();
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

#### Leave form3 as is

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
//button1 will be clicked to open a new form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;     // this = is the current form
    SignUp s = new SignUp();  //SignUp is the name of  my other form
    s.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't SignUp.Show()  neccesary ?

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewForm newForm = new NewForm();    //Create the New Form Object
    this.Hide();    //Hide the Old Form
    newForm.ShowDialog();    //Show the New Form
    this.Close();    //Close the Old Form
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 2):

you may consider this example

```
//Form1 Window
//EventHandler
Form1 frm2 = new Form1();
{
    frm2.Show(this); //this will show Form2
    frm1.Hide();  //this Form will hide
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a `Button` named as `Button1`. First click on it it will open the `EventHandler` of that `Button2` to call another `Form` you should write the following code to your Button.

```
your name example=form2.

form2 obj=new form2();

obj.show();
```

To close form1, write the following code:

`form1.visible=false;` 
or
`form1.Hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a bool so the algorithm would know when the button was activated. When it's clicked, the bool checks true, the new form shows and the last gets closed.

It's important to know that forms consume some ram (at least a little bit), so it's a good idea to close those you're not gonna use, instead of just hiding it. Makes the difference in big projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to control the opening of sub forms from a main form.

In my case I'm opening a Login window first before I launch my form1.  I control everything from Program.cs.  Set up a validation flag in Program.cs.  Open Login window from Program.cs.  Control then goes to login window.  Then if the validation is good, set the validation flag to true from the login window.  Now you can safely close the login window.  Control returns to Program.cs.  If the validation flag is true, open form1.  If the validation flag is false, your application will close.

In Program.cs:

```
   static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        //Validation flag
        public static bool ValidLogin = false;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


            Application.Run(new Login());

            if (ValidLogin)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }

    }
```

In Login.cs:

```
       private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == "x" && txtPassword.Text == "x")
            {
                Program.ValidLogin = true;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password are incorrect.");
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.Hide() instead of this.Close()

Answer (score 0):

Do this to Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace ProjectName 
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetDefaultCompatibleTextRendering(false);

            new Form1().Show();

            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my **opinion** it will be look like this:

```
        MoreActions objUI = new MoreActions();
        objUI.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run a particular form (or page) at first , apply below method
in program.cs
change the Application.Run(...) as

Application.Run(new form2()) //  in the place of form2 you change the form name which you want

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question. Here you launch a brand new Application (with its own top window). The question is about opening a new window from an existing one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).