# I have a strange problem in (Hide, show,close,showdialog) of Forms

Tags: c#

I have three Forms (`form1`, `form2`, `form3`). When `form1` loads it goes to `form2` by using this code:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

`form2` contains a button to show `form3` and hide `form2` by using this code in  the button:

```
Form3 frm = new Form3();
frm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

the problem is when I click on this button the application exits.

I need to show `form3` and hide `form2` when the button is clicked.

Comment: in your form 1 code, youve said on form2 going away, close form1, which shuts the app down.. most likely..

Comment: remove this.Close();

Comment: but i write the close after showdialog to form2 mean it need to close form2 to excute the close of form1

Comment: are you getting any exceptions? this.Close() is fine for form1 so that is not the problem.

Comment: @kamal, however Id bet that form1 is the main form of your app.  And when it closes, so will your application.

Comment: @BugFinder yes i know it main form but i make it use for first run and then the run begin from the form2  forthat i make form2 showdialog to be when it close the app close too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new form from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965043/how-to-open-a-new-form-from-another-form)

Comment: @kamal the this.close() will only run when the form2 exits "showdialog".. so its not actually running possibly when you thought.

Comment: Winforms will not allow you to Hide() a dialog, it will automatically close it.  You need to do this differently, Close() the form right away and Show() the next one.  To stop that from terminating your app, use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant That's right thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Hide()` against `Form2`, execution returns to the `ShowDialog()` line.

Instead of `ShowDialog()`, use `Show()`.  You can subscribe to the `FormClosed()` event to know when the form was closed.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.FormClosed += Frm_FormClosed;
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void Frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form3 frm = new Form3();
        frm.FormClosed += Frm_FormClosed;
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void Frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Form3:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```